# Using ArcGIS.com map that is not shared with everyone from ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I like to use the ArcGIS.com to create a map with operational layers on top of a baselayer. I would like to have the Content and Map as private but to show the map in an application built with JavaScript API. I tried using the new [IdentityManager](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2011/09/23/Version-2.5-of-the-ArcGIS-API-for-JavaScript-released-today.aspx) to make the application turn up a login dialog. It does, but I get: "Invalid username/password. Please try again."

[image]

I'm a newbie on ArcGIS.com and JS so might have mixed up something, does anyone know if it's possible to access maps that are not publicly shared? There is no problem to access the map using [createmap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/ags_createwebmapid.html) as long as the map is share to everyone.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The identity manager needs to do a POST to login to access your webmap. Since you're hitting arcgis.com, this is a cross domain request so you need to do this via a [proxy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/ags_proxy.htm). Have you set up a proxy for your app?

Looking at the docs, this isn't clear. We'll update our documentation to say you need to use a proxy if you want to use a private webmap in an app you host yourself (if you haven't guessed, I work on the JS API team).

Comment: Downvoted and no comment?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable answer to me....

Comment: Oh well, this is the Internet...

Comment: @Derek-Swingley I got the ASP.NET proxy up and running. But it would be great if the implementation would be able to get new tokens when needed.

Comment: @MathiasWestin glad to hear you got it working. The Identity Manager should be getting new tokens as needed- once your app tries to hit a resource with an expired token, the identity manager should kick in and get a new, valid token.

Comment: @Derek Swingley, isn't CORS enabled on arcgis.com? Wouldn't that allow connection to webmap without proxy?